# Is it possible to start own kernel driver without Microsoft Sign and with TESTSIGNING OFF? Windows 10 x64

Tags: certificate, driver, windows-10

OS: Windows 10 x64
I've created my own kernel driver which works fine with TESTSIGNING ON
I've signed .cat file with self-signed cert, and added cert to Trusted Root Authorities.

Now, I'm switching to TESTSIGNING OFF

I'm ABLE to install driver (it trusts my sign).
Installation via .inf file is successfull.

But when I'm trying to "sc start mydriver", it shows

[SC] StartService: error: 577: Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. bla bla bla

Did I do something wrong? Or its impossible to use own drivers at windows 10x64 without MS sign, and with TESTSIGNING OFF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not run kernel mode driver without MS signing. Windows 10 onward you will need Extended Validation Code Signing certificate (EV Certificate) for signing your driver. You can get more details from below link.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2015/04/01/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10/

Comment: Is that really true? I read something about being able to use Code Integrity policies which allow a custom CA to provide certs as long as "Secure Boot" is off.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your own driver, you can temporary disable driver signature enforcement by restarting your PC and selecting *Disable Driver Signature Enforcement*.

Find below the steps.

#### Windows 8 and above

1. Search and open *Recovery* in *System settings*.
2. Select *Advanced start-up* and *Restart now*.
3. During booting, in *Advanced Boot Options*, select *Disable Driver Signature Enforcement*.

<sup>Note: This setting will apply to a single user session.</sup>

[image: Windows 7 8 10, Advanced Boot Options, Disable Driver Signature Enforcement]

#### Windows 7

1. Restart PC.
2. Keep pressing F8 till *Advanced Boot Options* menu is shown.
3. Select *Disable Driver Signature Enforcement*.

---

Source: [How to Fix “Windows cannot verify the digital signature (Code 52)” Driver Problem?](http://freewisdoms.com/windows-cannot-verify-the-digital-signature-code-52-driver-fix/)